# ng-show | ng-hide: watch element height

Tags: angularjs, height, ng-show, ng-hide

I'm using this code to watch children height change:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return element.children().height();
},
function (newHeight) {
    if (newHeight) {
        element.height(newHeight);
    }
});
```

It works pretty well with `ng-if`, but `ng-show | ng-hide` doesn't fire height change event.
Is there any way to watch the height when I use `ng-show | ng-hide` directives?

---

Example:

```
<div class="form-slider">
  <div ng-if="step === 1" class="animate">
    <div ng-show="error">Error message</div>
    Some content
  </div>
  <div ng-if="step === 2" class="animate">
    <div ng-show="error">Error message</div>
    Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using animation to switch between `ng-if`s, so:
`.form-slider` has `position: relative`, while `.animate`: `position: absolute`. As you might know, html doesn't calculate height for `.form-slider` in this case and I have to use JS to change it's height.

Comment: could you add html how you are using `ng-if` & `ng-show`

Comment: how `step` & `error` value gets decided?

Comment: `error` attached to form, if form not value - show error. `step` value changes when user clicks go next|back.

Comment: What does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to fix this is to use `removeClass | addClass` events for `ng-hide` class:

```
myModule.animation('.ng-hide', function () {
  var changeHeight = function (element) {
    var container = element.closest('.my-selector');
    container.parent().height(container.height());
  };
  return { removeClass: changeHeight, addClass: changeHeight }
});
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but at least it works.

---

**Update**

I've found better solution. When you need to calculate height of your page using JS and you want to update height dynamically, when `ng-show | ng-hide` changes its state.

All what you need to do is just "extend" `ngShow & ngHide`:

```
(function () {
    var heightDirective = ['$rootScope', '$timeout', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.$watch(attrs.ngShow, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (!angular.equals(newVal, oldVal)) {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('element:heightChange', element.height());
                        }, 100);
                    }
                });
                $timeout(function () {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('element:heightChange', element.height());
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    }];
    angular.module('mean.system').directive('ngShow', heightDirective);
    angular.module('mean.system').directive('ngHide', heightDirective);
    angular.module('mean.system').directive('ngIf', heightDirective);
})();
```

Then, add listener into your controller or directive:

```
$rootScope.$on('element:heightChange', function () {
    element.height(element.children().height());
});
```